# Using polyfit with plotmatrix

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, plotmatrix

I have a matrix of subplots I created with plotmatrix, and want to add lines of best fit for each one, but can't figure out how to do it. Is there a way to apply polyfit to each subplot separately?

Here is a simplified example of what I have so far

```
x = randn(50,3);
y = x*[-1 2 1;2 0 1;1 -2 3;]';
[H,AX,BigAx,P,PAx] = plotmatrix(x,y);
```

I think I need to learn how to index over the matrix of subplots somehow.

Comment: post the code you already have

Comment: The code I have wouldn't really be that helpful, since there's a lot of irrelevant stuff but I'll try to come up with a similar example.

Comment: x = randn(50,3);
     y = x*[-1 2 1;2 0 1;1 -2 3;]';
     [H,AX,BigAx,P,PAx] = plotmatrix(x,y);

So here's an example of a matrix of scatter plots like I have. I literally don't know where to go from here. The best idea I have is to somehow create a for loop and create a polynomial for each section somehow but I'm not even sure how to index over the matrix of plots...

Comment: please update your question instead of posting additional information in the comments

Comment: yep just did it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to overlay an existing matrix produced by `plotmatrix`, but you can create the matrix yourself and overlay each subplot with the results from `polyfit`:

```
figure;
x = randn(50,3);
y = x*[-1 2 1;2 0 1;1 -2 3;]';

degree=4;

rows = size(x,2);
cols = size(y,2);

for k=1:rows
    for m=1:cols
        subplot(rows, cols, (k-1)*rows+m);
        hold all;
        scatter(x(:,k),y(:,m),'.');
        p = polyfit(x(:,k),y(:,m),degree);
        x_p = linspace(min(x(:,k)), max(x(:,k)));
        y_p = polyval(p,x_p);
        plot(x_p, y_p,'LineWidth',2);
        hold off;
    end
end
```

[image]